# Convert from MP4/MP3 to G.723.1

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg and using version 2.0.2 in my Linux server.

Could anyone please tell me how I can convert from mp4/mp3 files to a G.723.1 file format and G.723.1 to MP4?

Comment: Please ask one question per post. For your second question, you should post a new one on [SU], but please include the full, uncut command line output that you get—don't just say that it "does not work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an MP3 input file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a g723_1 -ar 8000 -ac 1 -b:a 6.3K output.wav
```

You need to specify the sample rate of 8 kHz, mono audio, and a bitrate of 6.3 kB/s.

---

In the other direction, from any audio file to AAC audio – which is the most common for MP4 containers – it's a little easier:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output.m4a
```

Read [the AAC encoding guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for more options. For example, if you don't have your 
ffmpeg configured with `libfdk_aac`, you can use `libfaac`, or the internal `aac` encoder:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 128k output.m4a
```